# Python and creating Excel-like tables of data

Tags: python, web-applications, automation

I am relatively new to (Python) programming and would like some direction for my current project.

I have been learning to web scrape and parse data. I am now sitting on a program that can create lots of information in the form of lists and dictionaries.

I now need a way to create formatted tables and output to some sort of web-based system. I am looking at tables of about 10-40 rows and 20 columns of alphanumeric (names and numbers) data. If I can produce basic bar/line charts that would be useful. It also needs to be entirely automated - the program will run once a day and download information. I need it to output seamlessly in report form to something like dropbox that I can access on-the-go. The table template will always be the same and will be heavily formatted (colouring mostly, like Excel conditional formatting).

I am also keen to learn to create web apps and I'm wondering if this is something I can do with this project? I'm not sure what I'll need to do and I'd like some direction. I'm pretty new to programming and the jargon is tough to wade through. Is it possible to create a website that takes automated input and creates good-looking data tables? Is this efficient? What are the available tools for this? If not efficient what are the other available options?